# In python, Read line by line in multiple files

Tags: python

In python how i can read lines of n number of .txt file, If 3-4 files are present can use the below command 3-4 times to open the file and to read lines, but ..

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
```

if there are 100 or more files are present how i can read only .txt files(if other extension files are present in the folder)

if 100 files are present I want to compare each line of the file with another file like

***file 1 - 2 ,  1-3,  1-4, ....1-99,  1-100, 2- 3, 2-4,  2-100, .....99-1, 99-2,..99-100***

if the comparison between 2 files can use the below method or import some dictionary and can do comparision

```
file1 = open('some_file_1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('some_file_2.txt', 'r')

for line1 in file1:
    for line2 in file2:
        if line1 == line2:
            print(file1)
            print(file2)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

I have no idea how I can compare each line of the files with another and print the same line present in the file
`ps: I want to print the result in the command prompt`

output expected

```
filenames   line
```

example output (filename unique and only format is same)
***filename is not the same only extension is same i.e

.txt***

```
filename1 and filename2 <tab>    same_statement_1
filename5 and filename12 and filename75 and filename81 <tab>  same_statement_29
filename8 and filename20  and filename78  <tab>  same_statement_17
filename56 and filename59  <tab>  same_statement_85
filename59 and filename97  <tab>  same_statement_101
```

Comment: Fair warning that **if** this is a homework question, any answer found here will be obviously cheating to your teacher/lecturer.  Answers may not complete the task in a way your teacher has taught.

Comment: @PhilipCouling This is not a homework question, This is a general task question. I am preparing for my interviews by solving these types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that your files are not unreasonably large, you could do a dictionary comprehension like

```
import os
filedata = { f: open(f, 'r').readlines() for f in os.listdir() if '.txt' == f[-4:] }
```

Then, to compare one file's line *n* to another you could just check whether

```
filedata['filename1.txt'][n] == filedata['filename2.txt'][n]
```

Comment: the file name is unique ***input_data.txt,   input_pins.txt,  modules_ref.txt, 
  macro_block.txt*** its not filename1, 2, 3....

Comment: Ghoti  #filedata['filename1.txt'][n] == filedata['filename2.txt'][n]    looks wrong because can't compare two files line by line in one line

Comment: The comprehension will create a dictionary for all files matching `*.txt` in the working directory, and the value of each key will be the lines of each file.  so `filedata['modules_ref.txt'][4]` would evaluate to a string representing the fifth line of that file, which could then be compared to any line from any other file in the dictionary quite easily.  Iterating through the dictionary's lists to find identical strings would be a relatively straightforward `for` loop looking for `string in filedata[file].values()` for each file in `filedata.keys()` so far as I can see.